# Passing Modified State to Outer Nested Decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

When nesting two Python decorators that store and change state information, what would be the best way to pass the state of the inner decorated function to the outer decorator?

For example, we may have decorators defined by

```py
def time_this(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) :
        start = time.process_time()
        rtn_val = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        wrapper.time_taken = time.process_time() - start
        return rtn_val
    return wrapper

def count_calls(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) :
        wrapper.num_calls += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs) 
    wrapper.num_calls = 0
    return wrapper
```

We could then decorate a function as follows

```py
@time_this
@count_calls
def my_func():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Hello World!")
```

However, if we then try

```py
my_func()
print(my_func.time_taken)
print(my_func.num_calls)
```

the output we get is

```
Hello World!
0.5007079059998887
0
```

(notice that the `num_calls` attribute is always 0.)

To clarify, I completely understand *why* this is happening, but I want to find out what the best way to resolve this issue is (so that the above code does what you hope it would, and updates `num_calls` in the wrapper).

Comment: The count shouldn't be zero after you run in

Comment: Also, you'd probably want to swap the order of the decorators, unless you want to time the count increment.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting an AttributeError?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It’s just a toy example, not actual code I’m using. Also the whole point of the question is that the count does end up being 0 after this is run.

Comment: @JohnDoe. Please run the code you posted. That's the whole point of an MCVE. We have to be talking about the same actual thing, instead of me guessing what you mean.

Comment: What is `functools.wrap`? Could you provide a link?

Comment: I can't get the code running. Get an AttributeError on `num_calls` whether it's with or without the `functools`. By the way I changed it to `wraps`

Comment: And that's why, as a rule, you must run the code you post.

Comment: Not very familiar with functools but I found [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) which I guess it's what he was going for

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sorry for my error, and thank you for being helpful and correcting it. :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry about the small syntax error. I had run the code, but for *reasons* had to copy it onto a different device to post here which is where typos in copying were introduced. I have checked it and re run it now, so it should work. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

You could set a dict with results to wrapper, this dict will be shared among the decorators:

```
import functools
import time

def time_this(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) :
        time1 = time.time()
        rtn_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        time2 = time.time()
        wrapper.results['time_this'] += (time2 - time1) * 1000.0
        return rtn_val

    results = getattr(wrapper, 'results', {})
    results['time_this'] = 0
    setattr(wrapper, 'results', results)

    return wrapper

def count_calls(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) :
        rtn_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapper.results['count_calls'] = wrapper.results['count_calls'] + 1
        return rtn_val

    results = getattr(wrapper, 'results', {})
    results['count_calls'] = 0
    setattr(wrapper, 'results', results)

    return wrapper


@time_this
@count_calls
def my_func():
    print("Hello World!")

for i in range(10):
    my_func()

print(my_func.results)
print('avg:', my_func.results['time_this'] / my_func.results['count_calls'])
```

Prints:

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
{'count_calls': 10, 'time_this': 0.03719329833984375}
avg: 0.003719329833984375
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the reason `num_calls` is a static 0 in the outer wrapper is that that [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) updates the wrapper [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__), which freezes it at the original value. There are a couple of ways of dealing with this.

If you know the sequence of decorators, you can use the [`__wrapped__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) attribute that it creates in the wrapper to access the actual attribute:

```
print(my_func.__wrapped__.num_calls)
```

Another option is to look into the additional arguments to `wraps`. By default `__dict__` is updated. But why not just reassign it to the new object:

```
def mywraps(wrapped):
    return functools.wraps(wrapped, assigned=functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS + ('__dict__',),
                           updated=())

def time_this(func):
    @mywraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) :
        start = time.process_time()
        rtn_val = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        wrapper.time_taken = time.process_time() - start
        return rtn_val
    return wrapper

def count_calls(func):
    @mywraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) :
        wrapper.num_calls += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs) 
    wrapper.num_calls = 0
    return wrapper
```

Now all the function objects in the chain share the same manually assigned attributes since

```
>>> my_func.__dict__ is my_func.__wrapped__.__dict__ is my_func.__wrapped__.__wrapped__.__dict__
True
```

You don't strictly need the `mywraps` decorator. I just provided it as a convenience to avoid having to set the arguments for `wraps` every time, just like `wraps` itself is a convenience for `update_wrapper`.